# checkboxes filtering object and array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, filtering

I want the filter functionality to work just like this fiddle in the first comment below but without catching the checkboxes category from ng-repeat, I just want to write the checkboxes' value and get the filtered words as they written in the checkboxes' value in HTML.

Comment: [this is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wYfs4/688/)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/739/

Comment: thank you so much, I am so grateful for your help because I have been stuck in this from a week.

Comment: Glad I helped. Happy coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this just like normal checkboxes- only catch is that the value should be properly bound using `ng-model` to the required controller property.

```
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter.red" value="red"> Red <br>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter.white" value="white"> White <br>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter.champagne" value="champagne">Champagne
```